# assertcontains() not working while reading text from PDF

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pdf-reader

I have downloaded the PDF file and trying to compare run time result with PDF data. I have captured data in following way. And using assertcontains() for a specific line but that line in PDF is getting break. So assertcontains() giving result false.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
content= PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);
System.out.println("Page Content is " + content);
```

Page Content is -

079 001311A0 EARLINGTO ATWR 37.3804129

N NORTH -

NEBO

And assertion is like -

```
assertlib.assertcontains(driver, logger,content, "EARLINGTON NORTH - NEBO");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `assertcontains` looks for the whole thing, ie. if you `assertcontains(..., "A B C")` and the string is `A - B C` it fails because of the `- `

Comment: @RC. PDF is displaying data as above. There are categories first is number then Id then Name.... . But the Name in PDF getting in next line so assert get fails. Is there any way to compare my expected data with the PDF data?